# Adding data attribute to a Class Literal in Jade

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I want to write the equivalent of this html in jade

```
<div class="carousel" data-transition="slide">
<div>
```

I wrote it like this, which is not the correct syntax

```
.carousel (data-transition= "slide")
```

I can't find anything in the docs for an answer. Thanks ahead of time your answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You were close, though:

```
.carousel(data-transition = "slide")
```

(leave out the space between `carousel` and the parentheses).

Comment: Still not working when I do that (data-transition= "slide") ##

Comment: @mibbit it does for me: the exact string in my answer generates the HTML that you're looking for. What are you getting instead?